# Rendering transparent mesh with overlapping triangles in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to render a transparent shape consisting of several overlapping triangles. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.2
});


mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 1));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -200, 1));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(200, -200, 1));

geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(200, 0, 1));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, -200, 1));
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3,4,5));
```

Here's a jsfiddle to illustrate my problem http://jsfiddle.net/7wk0cfcj/

The above code works well, except there's a darker area in the middle of the shape(due to overlapping of triangles). I'd like the mesh to appear as single transparent object with the same colour everywhere. Is there a way to achieve this without changing the triangles so that they don't overlap?

Comment: You could try using a combinatory plugin, like [threeCSG](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG) (the CSG stands for constructive solid geomtry). The plugin combines simple geometry together to form complex shapes. It's a pretty light plugin and super easy to use.

Comment: why do you want to make it transparent? Just give it solid color. if triangle it transparent it will surely show overlap.

Comment: since you do have the vertices, instead of rendering triangles, you can render a polygon.

Comment: Render the triangles to a texture using an opaque material. Then render the texture as a semi-transparent overlay with opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Z value is always the same, you could change the z test function on the material to prevent drawing twice in the same spot for your selection.

This feature is not released yet in three.js; its in the dev branch.

http://jsfiddle.net/fgaudet/7wk0cfcj/5/ with a external ref to the dev branch...

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.2,
    depthFunc: THREE.LessDepth
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed. You can also do it in current three.js release using `renderer.context.depthFunc(renderer.context.LESS)`

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Material:

`blending: THREE.NoBlending`

The downside is you cant see through anymore, so an object behind the triangles is invisible.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wk0cfcj/2/

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I want. My usecase is that I want to allow the user to highlight an area on the screen. And I don't want an area to get darker if the user draws over it twice.